# Is there any flutter package that supports Kafka?

Tags: flutter, dart, apache-kafka

I have been designing an app in flutter that needs to use Kafka for stream messages. So far i have found [dart-kafka](https://github.com/dart-kafka/kafka) and [flutter-kafka](https://pub.dev/packages/kafka), but former package does not supports current flutter sdk and the latter does not have any documentation. Is there any way to consume/produce topics using flutter other than REST proxy?